# AngularJS input binding with filter

Tags: angularjs

I have two input fields that need to be bound. One input represents acres and the other one represents square feet.
When you update either one, the other one should update as well, applying the proper conversion formula.
The catch is that I only want o show two decimals.

Markup:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="acres">
<input type="text" ng-model="sqft">
```

Controller:

```
$scope.$watch('acres', function () {
    $scope.sqft = $filter('number')(($scope.acres / 5.23565), 2);
});

$scope.$watch('sqft', function () {
    $scope.acres = $filter('number')(($scope.sqft * 5.54841), 2);
});
```

Comment: This should get you going http://jsfiddle.net/lancelarsen/Tx7Ty/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `ng-change` instead of using `$watch`

Markup:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="acres" ng-change="acresChanged()">
<input type="text" ng-model="sqft" ng-change="sqftChanged()">
```

Controller:

```
$scope.acresChanged = function() {
   $scope.sqft = $filter('number')(($scope.acres / 5.23565), 2);
};

$scope.sqftChanged = function() {
   $scope.acres = $filter('number')(($scope.sqft * 5.54841), 2);
};
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/CyqG5tYhRynkVyBekUx0?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
$scope.$watch('acres', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal !== oldVal) {
       $scope.sqft = $filter('number')((newVal/ 5.23565), 2);
    }
});
```

But now you can't do the same for `sqft` or you will end with an infinite loop.